# Amend jQuery image rotator to loop just once

Tags: jquery

I want to adapt a script which rotates a sequence of images infinitely so that it only goes through the sequence once. Can I return a false somewhere to end the loop? Where does it need to go? The script I am trying to adapt can be found at http://marktyrrell.com/labs/blueberry/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

my previous answer was overcomplicated, if you need to stop the carousel at the last image you can just revert to the original code and then add the line below

```
//primary function to change slides
var rotate = function(){
    /* ADDED */ if (next == 0) return;
    //fade out current slide and remove active class,
    //fade in next slide and add active class
    slides.eq(current).fadeOut(o.duration).removeClass('active')
```

this will stop the execution when the next image is the first of the sequence.

**previous answer**

i marked with `/* changed */` the changes you need in the jquery.blueberry.js

it's not tested ;)

```
//primary function to change slides
var rotate = function(/* changed */ stop){
    /* changed */ var stopNext = current >= slides.length-1 ? true : false;
    //fade out current slide and remove active class,
    //fade in next slide and add active class
    slides.eq(current).fadeOut(o.duration).removeClass('active')
        .end().eq(next).fadeIn(o.duration).addClass('active')
        .queue(function(){
            //add rotateTimer function to end of animation
            //this prevents animation buildup caused by requestAnimationFrame
            //rotateTimer starts a timer for the next rotate
            /* changed */ if (!stop) rotateTimer(stopNext);
            $(this).dequeue()
        });
    //update pager to reflect slide change
    if(pager){
        pager.eq(current).removeClass('active')
            .end().eq(next).addClass('active');
    }

    //update current and next vars to reflect slide change
    //set next as first slide if current is the last
    current = next;
    next = current >= slides.length-1 ? 0 : current+1;
};
var rotateTimer = function(/* changed */ stopNext){
    obj.play = setTimeout(function(){
        //trigger slide rotate function at end of timer
        rotate(/* changed */ stopNext);
    }, o.interval);
};
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you so much! I've popped all my code into a JSFiddle, because the pause doesn't take effect at the end of the first sequence, but part way through the second: http://jsfiddle.net/c8p453wr/7/

Answer (score 0):

You could simply remove or comment line number 110 in `jquery.blueberry.js`:

```
//update current and next vars to reflect slide change
//set next as first slide if current is the last
current = next;
// next = current >= slides.length-1 ? 0 : current+1;
```

Comment: I tried this, thanks, but it only does the first 2 images (I have 4 in total) and then it fades the latter one in and out over and over. I want to go through the sequence once and then stop it on the final image - and pause it there.

Answer (score -1):

Change this line:

```
next = current >= slides.length-1 ? 0 : current+1;
```

to

```
next = current >= slides.length-1 ? current : current+1;
```

Comment: I tried this, thanks, but when it gets to the end of the sequence it then fades the final image in and out over and over rather than just stopping on the last image and keeping it in place.

Comment: add this then: `clearTimeout(obj.play);` when `current==slides.length-1`